# Python 2 -> Python 3 re.sub

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm new at Python and I would appreciate if someone could help.
I have a little script in py2 that I would like to convert to py3. In py2 this works fine but in py3 it gives an error. If someone could help me fix this I would verry much appreciate it.

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Cuca\Downloads\saspy-master\site.py", line 46, in <module>
    asd = re.sub(r'([0-9, a-z, A-Z])(?!$)', r'\\1,', state)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\re.py", line 208, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

**From the code**

```
counters = [0x01,0x0F]        
ser.write(counters)
        a = ser.read(30)
        state = binascii.hexlify(a)
        asd = re.sub(r'([0-9, a-z, A-Z])(?!$)', r'\\1,', state)
        url = 'http://127.0.0.1/sastest/index.php'
        myobj = {'key':asd}
        x = requests.post(url, data = asd)
        print(asd)
```

What I want to do is read from a devices through serial communication and the data that I recive should go to that url with a "," sign between each character of data.

Thank you

Comment: `state` is a bytestring. Try `asd = re.sub(rb'([0-9, a-z, A-Z])(?!$)', rb'\\1,', state)`

Comment: `asd = re.sub(rb'([0-9, a-z, A-Z])(?!$)', rb'\1,', state)` without the second backslash work perfect, thank you